# BVN.404Handler. Adding redirect suggestions automatically from EPiServer scheduled job.

Tags: redirect, job-scheduling, episerver, episerver-7

I am using a scheduled job that moves outdated events to a folder called "Past events". After the event have been moved, I want to change the event page's url from its old one to the new so it matches the hierarchy of its new location. For this, I am using a custom redirect gadget called BVN.404Handler.

```
if(Configuration.Logging == LoggerMode.On && Upgrader.Valid)
        {
            Logger.LogRequest(urlNotFound, referer);
        }
```

The line of code above only logs a suggestion of the old url and the new one. 
Since this is a scheduled job that moves pages based on their endDate value i need to make the redirect gadget register the url mappings automatically. With the current solution, a user needs to manually open the gadget and confirm the mapping by pasting the newurl (known referrers) value into the textfield and pressing "Add".

This is what it looks like: 
[Image of BVN.404Handler gadget](http://s3.postimg.org/q7xy8yspf/Sk_rmklipp.png)

Is this possible to achieve with the current version of this gadget?

```
  <package id="BVN.404Handler" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45"
```

Or do anyone know a possible workaround for achieving this?

Thanks in advance
/ Carl

Comment: The BVN.404 stores the redirects in a very simple sql table, it seems as a perfectly fine solution to perform your CRUD operations directly to that table.

Answer (score 0):

This is code fragment that Gadget uses itself to store custom redirect:

```
new DataStoreHandler().SaveCustomRedirect(
    new CustomRedirect(oldUrl.Trim(),
                       newUrl.Trim(),
                       (skipWildCardAppend == null) ? false : true));
```

You can give it a try and fill in with your own required data.